# Error in adding recurrence event in Calendar

Tags: android, events, calendar, android-calendar, rrule

Hi I am tring to Create an app which add events to calendar. For example I need to create an event on every Saturday until dec 31ist.
  The following are the attributes that I set for creating events,

```
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, sDate);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION,"P50S");
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, hasAlarm);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA;UNTIL=20151230");
mContext.getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, event);
```

But it create an event for the given date (sDate) and then create every Saturday. But how can I avoid that one event which created on given date (sDate)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to check your reccurrence rule for day of week and offset your DTSTART to the nearest Saturday (or any other weekday that your recurrence rule contains). To give you rough example how to do that I'm attaching code from Android Calendar app that offsets start time and end time of the event based on reccurence rule string, and returns two long values - new start time and new end time if offset was applied, or null if it wasn't. EventRecurrence class can be found via search on GrepCode, its part of Android calendar app

```
public static long[] offsetStartTimeIfNecessary(long startMilis, long endMilis, String rrule) {
    if (rrule == null || rrule.isEmpty() || rrule.replace("RRULE:", "").isEmpty()) {
        // No need to waste any time with the parsing if the rule is empty.
        return null;
    }
    long result[] = new long[2];
    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.setTimeInMillis(startMilis);
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.setTimeInMillis(endMilis);
    EventRecurrence mEventRecurrence = new EventRecurrence();
    mEventRecurrence.parse(rrule.replace("RRULE:", ""));
    // Check if we meet the specific special case. It has to:
    //  * be weekly
    //  * not recur on the same day of the week that the startTime falls on
    // In this case, we'll need to push the start time to fall on the first day of the week
    // that is part of the recurrence.
    if (mEventRecurrence.freq != EventRecurrence.WEEKLY) {
        // Not weekly so nothing to worry about.
        return null;
    }
    if (mEventRecurrence.byday == null ||
            mEventRecurrence.byday.length > mEventRecurrence.bydayCount) {
        // This shouldn't happen, but just in case something is weird about the recurrence.
        return null;
    }
    // Start to figure out what the nearest weekday is.
    int closestWeekday = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int weekstart = EventRecurrence.day2TimeDay(mEventRecurrence.wkst);
    int startDay = startTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mEventRecurrence.bydayCount; i++) {
        int day = EventRecurrence.day2TimeDay(mEventRecurrence.byday[i]);
        if (day == startDay) {
            // Our start day is one of the recurring days, so we're good.
            return null;
        }
        if (day < weekstart) {
            // Let's not make any assumptions about what weekstart can be.
            day += 7;
        }
        // We either want the earliest day that is later in the week than startDay ...
        if (day > startDay && (day < closestWeekday || closestWeekday < startDay)) {
            closestWeekday = day;
        }
        // ... or if there are no days later than startDay, we want the earliest day that is
        // earlier in the week than startDay.
        if (closestWeekday == Integer.MAX_VALUE || closestWeekday < startDay) {
            // We haven't found a day that's later in the week than startDay yet.
            if (day < closestWeekday) {
                closestWeekday = day;
            }
        }
    }
    if (closestWeekday < startDay) {
        closestWeekday += 7;
    }
    int daysOffset = closestWeekday - startDay;
    startTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysOffset);
    endTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysOffset);
    result[0] = startTime.getTimeInMillis();
    result[1] = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
    return result;
}
```